# Pipe and select operators in RxJS

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I'm wondering whether the following two blocks of code behave in the same manner:

With pipe (from original ngrx [sample](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/17bf6f96232f12a3b1b0663bb5c24705e5463f3d/projects/example-app/src/app/auth/containers/login-page.component.ts#L20-L21)):

```
pending$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromAuth.selectLoginPagePending));
error$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromAuth.selectLoginPageError));
```

And without one:

```
pending$ = this.store.select(fromAuth.selectLoginPagePending);
error$ = this.store.select(fromAuth.selectLoginPageError);
```

I've tested both and haven't noticed any apparent difference.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Both

```
pending$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromAuth.selectLoginPagePending));
error$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromAuth.selectLoginPageError));
```

and

```
pending$ = this.store.select(fromAuth.selectLoginPagePending);
error$ = this.store.select(fromAuth.selectLoginPageError);
```

carry out the same function, which is to obtain a slice of the store state , as described on the NgRX documentation on [selectors](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#selectors).

However, the `pipe()` utility allows you to chain the selector with [RxJS pipeable operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/), such as `scan()`, and `filter()`, allowing you to carry out other operations such as state transitions.

Comment: Does it mean there is no difference in the case of no more operators will be added?

Answer (score 1):

They both do the same thing.
Internally, the `store.select` function calls the `select` operator.